# Why a new Android Studio project gets a classpath error as soon is created?

Tags: android, android-studio, classpath

I'm trying to create a new project from scratch using the "Bottom Navigation Activity" model but as soon the IDE (Android Studio) tries to build app all I get a ton of red lines.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.4.2
> project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.4.2
> > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.5' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.5')

I mean, this should have no errors, since is a model were you start from, I didn't added or deleted a single line of code, so, Why I get this errors.?

Also, I have many apps and due to Google new politics I must to update something and that leads to a ton of errors that took me a week to solve. I mean, last time I compiled the code it was working fine, 6 months later all the lines are in red.
Is really frustrating. There's any other IDE that is more solid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says on your error code the `Gradle plugin version 7.4.2` is built for Java 11, your project is set for Java 8.

there is a work around for that.

> Updating your Java Version on your `build.gradle` (app-level)

try updating your `compileOptions` and `kotlinOptions` to  `JavaVersion.VERSION_11`

looks like this:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

if you want to stick with Java 8. consider downgrading. Go to your project-level build.gradle change version to com.android.tools.build:`gradle:7.0.0`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
}
```

also check your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to see if your Gradle version matches with your Gradle plugin version.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that that worked, I did it on the UI but now I get this error, --error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.myremotepro.databinding.FragmentDashboardBinding;-- Should I create a new Question for this?

Comment: There's a list that let me know what Gradle goes with what JAVA? How should I search for this?

Comment: Go to your Gradle Scripts and to your build.gradle (app-level) again and enable your ViewBinding.

it will look like this:

android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
Sync gradle, clean and rebuild your project. see if it helps.